# How to upload media to S3 using entity browser and Flysystem S3 module

Tags: 8

My site is configured to upload media images to S3 using the flysystem module.

However when I want to use the entity browser it's default configuration is to upload images to the filesystem.

Is there a way to change the upload location to use the same S3 location?

What syntax should be used in the "Upload location" field below?

[image: flysystems3]
[image: entitybrowseruploadlocation]

Comment: Probably the url that [line 266 in S3.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/flysystem_s3/tree/src/Flysystem/S3.php?h=8.x-1.x#n266) returns. Dump it out and copy that URL.

Comment: It was simply "s3://", thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload location was simply "s3://"